# Unexpected behavior from `NumberForm` of a matix

Tags: number-representation

If I calculate the dimension of the matrix after `NumberForm` directly, then there will be something wrong

```
test = NumberForm[IdentityMatrix[2], 2];
test // Dimensions
(*output {2}, but {2,2} is expected*)
```

If I show the result of `NumberForm` and then calculate the dimension, the result is right

```
{{"1","0"},{"0","1"}} //Dimensions
(*ouput {2,2}*)
```

What causes this? Is it a bug?

Comment: Please do not add the [tag:bugs] tag to your *own* questions. This is a special tag that is meant to be added by someone else than the original poster, after the bug has been verified by the community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug:

```
Head[test]
(* NumberForm *)
```

Generally all `*Form` function, including `NumberForm`, `MatrixForm`, etc. are wrappers that are meant to *display* the expression only. In fact the output indicates the presence of the wrapper:

[image]

Once the expression is wrapped, it is not suitable for calculations.  Or you need to extract it to do calculations.

```
MatrixQ[test]
(* False *)

MatrixQ[First[test]]
(* True *)

Dimensions[First[test]]
(* {2, 2} *)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there any function similar to `NumberForm` which does change the number to a string (not displays the expression only)?

Comment: @EdenHarder `ToString`.  But you must apply it to numbers individually, not to a list of numbers.  You can also use `ToString@NumberForm[number]`.

Comment: Isn't `StandardForm` an exception?

Comment: @QuantumDot No. The confusing bit is that `SomeForm[x]` then `%` gives `x` and not `SomeForm[x]`.  `Out` treats these forms specially and doesn't record them.  See `$OutputForms`.