# Coefficient on expression in InputForm

Tags: expression-manipulation, coefficients

I am having trouble understanding what is going wrong when trying to use the Coefficient function on expressions in InputForm. A very simple example serves to illustrate.

```
In[1]:= a = 3 x + 4 y // InputForm

Out[1]//InputForm=
3*x + 4*y

In[2]:= Coefficient[a, x]

Out[2]= 0
```

Is there any way to make this work, or convert the old expression back into Standard form? Cheers!

Comment: (Sadly,) many functions in MMA do not work with `...Form` wrappers the way you might expect (i.e. by simply ignoring them). If you look at the `FullForm` of `a`, you'll see that everything is wrapped inside `InputForm`. And an expression of the form `InputForm[...]` has coeffient `0` for `x`, so the result you're getting is technically correct

Comment: I guess this is the answer: [131982](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131982/5478)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `FullForm` to see what `a` really is, as

```
a = 3 x + 4 y // InputForm
a // FullForm
(*  InputForm[Plus[Times[3,x],Times[4,y]]]  *)
```

We see that `a` has the head `InputForm`.  What we want to pass to `Coefficient` is the expression that has the head `Plus`.  We can do that with

```
Coefficient[a//First,x]
(*  3  *)
```

Do we really need the head of `a` to be `InputForm`?  If not, we could use parentheses like this

```
(a = 3 x + 4 y) // InputForm
(*  3*x + 4*y  *)

Coefficient[a,x]
(*  3  *)
```

Comment: OK! great, thank you, looks like I need to learn a bit about "head" in mathematica